# Any way to tell mercurial that file changed name?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

this is kind of an boring question because I know how to almost do it, but the point is that I would like to see is there a better way than remove old file, add new file... I know TortoiseHg autodetects it, but that file has a separate history when I use TortoiseHg to anonnate it... 
So is there a way to tell the mercurial this is a renamed file?
Please note I mix a bit here TortoiseHg and Mercurial, I know that one is DVCS, the other one is GUI for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks as though you are looking for `hg rename`:

The command

```
hg rename old new
```

will rename a file from `old` to `new` and register the rename. If you have already renamed the file, then

```
hg rename --after old new
```

will tell mercurial that the file has been renamed and that it should track it under the new name.

Comment: To be clear `--after` is for if you have already renamed the file on disk but haven't yet committed it.  If you've already committed after renaming the file you're not able to store the rename info -- that ship has sailed.

Comment: This is helpful and lovely, but … can it be improved further? Specifically, I typically want to rename `.h` & `.m` pairs. Also, the old name, which is no longer in the file system, doesn't tab complete on the console.